# Anyone know of tree structured jQuery select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm looking for an select box replacement, in which I am choosing a node of tree (the hierarchical structure is important). The other import thing is the ability to typefilter the nodes, because there is a lot of records.

Best if this could be in jQuery, ideally using jQuery UI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All you're looking for is in the [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) jQuery plugin. Beautifully written, modular, extremely configurable, 5+ star implementation of hierarchical data display in a javascript rendered tree.

Comment: +1 Seems still actively maintained today and well stared on github

Answer (score 7):

Checkout the ComboTree plugin by EasyUI.

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

Comment: This looks like a nice component - too bad it is not really free

Comment: There is a freeware license (http://www.jeasyui.com/license_freeware.php), but you are right in the sense that it is a bit restrictive.

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting plugin useful in situation like yours. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/